# How to Identify an Office 365 User Account from inside an Excel Add in

Tags: office-addins, excel-addins, office-js

I would like to understand if there is any API which can help us find the Office 365 user account information from my Excel add-in javascript code.
Eg- Let's assume a user with Office email account abc@xyz.com launches Excel, downloads my add-in from Office store and uses it.
I want to capture this user info from my app for the various users who downloaded/using my app.
Is there an API in apps for office to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not currently an API in Office add-ins in Word/Excel/PowerPoint that exposes the user information for the person logged on to the Office clients.

In Outlook add-ins you can retrieve this information.

```
// Example: Allie Bellew
console.log(Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.displayName);

// Example: allieb@contoso.com
console.log(Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.emailAddress);
```

See the [userProfile object documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/outlook/office.userprofile) for more information.

Comment: url is broken, please amend

Answer (score 1):

To add to Doug's response:  while it doesn't expose the user's email address, you can get a unique identifier for the user from the entitlement token, provided your app is in the Office Store.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164035.aspx for more info.

The UserId property of the entitlement token response (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/verificationsvc.verifyentitlementtokenresponse_members.aspx) is the purchaser ID. Per the documentation above, "This is an encrypted value of the Microsoft account used by the person who purchased the app".

Hope this helps,

~ Michael Zlatkovsky, developer on Office Extensibility team, MSFT