# Identifying user account from Excel

Tags: office-js

I have seen this post [Get excel user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37071639/how-to-identify-an-office-365-user-account-from-inside-an-excel-add-in) and saw that there is no such possibility. I have done research and found only one way to get these details if logged in with Microsoft Graph, I was wondering if at this moment of time the Office.js api has been made to expose the user's details as such.

Answer (score 0):

While it is still in Preview, you may want to take a look at [Enable SSO in an add-in](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins). This will give you a Graph token, allowing you to quickly grab the user's profile information.